# How to Get bitmap that appear on specific time on jpeg clip?

Tags: c#, video, video-capture

I have some jpeg clip ( total clip time is 55 seconds )
I want to isolate the bitmap that appear after 40 seconds of the clip.

How can i do it ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this concept of a 'jpeg clip'; is it a Motion JPEG? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG

Comment: Yes ( MJPEG · Motion JPEG 2000 · MPEG-1 · MPEG-2 (Part 2) · MPEG-4 (Part 2/ASP · Part 10/AVC)

Comment: Well, it is simple if you have a good decoder library for the video format.  Which isn't so simple to find, they are written in C, cost money and just plain hard to find for obscure formats like MJPEG.

Comment: And what about disassemble jpeg clip to bitmap collection ( bitmap array ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using FFMpeg: http://muzso.hu/2008/12/28/extracting-thumbnails-still-images-frames-from-a-video-with-ffmpeg

If you need to implement functionality like this in your own application (and don't want to invoke ffmpeg from it), you can use [libavcodec](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/wiki/index.php?title=C_Sharp), which is what powers ffmpeg. Note that the [C# adaptation](http://www.informikon.com/blog/a-first-draft.html) is still in development.